# What does "~" do to an int in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to negate a boolean mask I've come across this behavior:
`~1` gives `-2`, `~0` gives `-1`.
I somewhat remember this pattern from my System Programming class. Has it something to do with the two's or one's complement?

Thanks, I was able to negate it, I'm just curious about what this does.

Comment: it's exactly two complement, as integers don't have a 16/32/64 whatever size in python

Comment: check `bitwise operator` https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_bitwise_operators.asp

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ah, I see, thanks a lot, I used a converter online and it didn't give the same answer as the two's complement and I wasn't sure.

Comment: @Epsi95 Thank you!